# Partial differentiation of double integrals.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let 
\begin{equation}
H(x,y)  = \int_0^{f(x)} \int_0^{g(y)} h(s,t) \, ds\,dt
\end{equation}

where $f,g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable. Is there a standard way of computing the partial derivatives of $H$. It seems like it shouldn't be difficult, but its proven to be more complicated than I hoped.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$ \int h(s,t)ds =A(s,t) +{\cal C}(t). $$

Then:

$$ H(x,y) = \int_0^{f(x)} \left(A(g(y),t)-A(0,t)\right) dt$$

$$\partial_1 H(x,y) = A(g(y),f(x))f'(x)-A(0,f(x)) f'(x)$$
$$ = f'(x)\int_0^{g(y)} h(s,f(x))ds$$

$$\partial_2 H(x,y) = \int_0^{f(x)} \partial_1 A(g(y),t)g'(y)dt$$
$$  = g'(y)\int_0^{f(x)} h(g(y),t)dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Since apparently $H$ only depends on $x$ through $f(x)$, you can do this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(x,y) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x)}\int_0^{f(x)}\int_0^{g(y)}h(s,t)\,ds\,dt = f'(x)\int_0^{g(y)}h(f(x),t)\,dt$$

as long as $f'(x)$ exists.

The same argument applies for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}H(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\,\partial y}H(x,y)$, given that $x$ and $y$ are independent. Beyond that, I don't think there's anything special you can do.

Comment: I think it should be $h(f(x),t)$ in the final remaining integral, since the fundamental theorem was used to find the derivative.

Comment: @coffeemath indeed, thanks for catching that, I've fixed it