# Partial differential of double integral

Tags: real-analysis

This problem is similar to 
[Partial differentiation of double integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081943/partial-differentiation-of-double-integrals)

but I don't know how to find partial derivatives of H 
\begin{equation}
H(x,y)  = \int_0^{f(x,y)} \int_0^{g(x,y)} h(s,t) \, ds\,dt
\end{equation}

where $f,g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable.

For example, 
I have to prove that 
$$H(x,y)=1/2\int_0^{x} ds \int_{s-x+y}^{x+y-s} h(s,t) \,dt$$
satisfying 
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}H(x,y)-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}H(x,y)=h$$

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule will do the trick hand-in-hand with the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x } \cdot \int_0^{g(x,y)} h(s,f(x,y))\:ds + \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} \cdot \int_0^{f(x,y)} h(g(x,y),t)\:dt$$

This is because there are only two dependence "trees" where $H$ depends on $x$: through the $s$ integral and the $t$ integral (there are, for example, no dependences in the integrand, yet). The more dependence branches there are, the more terms you add to the derivative due to chain rule. Can you proceed from here?